# Set a background rectangle for my code in lstlisting?

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, code

Here's my beamer frame:

```
\defverbatim[colored]\sleepSort{
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=python,tabsize=2]
    var = 3 list print
      \end{lstlisting}}
      \begin{frame}{Variáveis}

      \begin{itemize}
        \item Armazenamento de dados
        \Declaração

      \end{itemize} 

        \sleepSort

      \end{frame}
```

My piece of code is on the same background everything else. How can I put the code on a rectangle of another color?

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @samcarter I was just about to do the same :)

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one question.

Comment: Related (same solution should work): [How to highlight sections of my code in algorithm?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/386272). Or even simpler, probably would be to use the `tcolorbox` package which has specific support for `listings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As there is no MWE in the question and I don't want to find out how `\defverbatim` is to be used I put the listing directly in the frame.*

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python,tabsize=2,backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}]
var = 3 list print
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does unfortunately not work for every theme. I had an occurance, where this was rendered as lines with a yellow background with the background color of the frame visible between them.

Comment: @mat May be it would be nice, if you can ask a new question with your concerns, because, the `samcater/user36296` is suspended from this site and therefore, she cannot answer.

Comment: @Raaja: I added a reference and expanded the solution

Comment: @mat I dont completely understand your comment.

Comment: My edit was rejected. Unfortunately I cannot post the solution as a new answer, since the question is closed:
To get a solid background for a listing, you can use the *mdframe* environment as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348795/create-new-environment-with-mdframed-and-listin):
 
`\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow]  \begin{lstlisting}language=python,tabsize=2]
...  \end{lstlisting} \end{mdframed}`

Comment: samca**r**ter (as a cat I know that they are not involved in catering ;-)